# Failed to localise android-ndk installed from homebrew

Tags: macos, gradle, android-ndk, homebrew

I have installed SDK doing `brew cask install android-ndk` and NDK doing `brew cask install android-ndk`, everything was ok during the installation and inserted the `PATH`, like this:

```
export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/opt/gradle
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/usr/local/Caskroom/android-ndk/16b/android-ndk-r16b
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397
export PATH=$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

Saved and committed doing `source ~/.bash_profile`.

After, I tried to run my gradle task, during start of compile of a C++ library, I got this:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':some-library'.
> NDK not configured. 
  Download it with SDK manager.
```

Is there any way to solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In macOS installed with `brew` use this the following paths

In file **~/.bash_profile**

```
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME = /usr/local/share/android-ndk
export ANDROID_HOME = /usr/local/share/android-sdk
```

If you are using another bash script or zsh for example, you should put it begin of that script file, eg.

**myortherscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# THIS AT TOP
source ~/.bash_profile
```

**Important:** This sample I'm considering the same user for configuration bash_profile and script execution.